# connecting new column to visual studio through accdb

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have created a winform app connected to an access database as datasource ,
but now i have added a column in access database & now i have to provide the same field in winform for data entry purpose.
But now in my data source the new field is not visible even after refreshing .
any help in solving this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to open the dataset, right click on the relevant table adapter (`MSdiesTableAdapter`), choose `Configure` and then go through the wizard, adding the new column to the SELECT sql. When you finish the wizard the new column will appear in the datatable.

It won't have appeared in any databound grid etc - you'll also have to go to those grids and do an "Edit Columns" and "Add a New Column", choose "DataBound Column" and pick the new column. You can also, as a quick trick, remove the "DataMember" setting from the bindingsource the grid is bound to, then put it back

Microsoft never intended for DataSets and databases to be perfectly aligned; the dataset is your client side store of info and it may have more or fewer columns than the database, and have stuff it calculates itself locally, or relationships that are different to the database. This is why it needs manually adding and working through

Comment: One tip, by the way, for working with tableadapters; try to avoid ever clicking on the `[...]` button next to an SQL query in the Properties grid. It opens the Query Builder which does an awesome job of reformatting and rephrasing (i.e. ruining) your nicely formatted SQL, making it harder to edit the second time around